# Email not validating completely with jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, email

Email address not validating completely for example. i have a email field and i am validating it from jQuery validation plugin. when i put some like "abbcss" it says email is not valid. then i put "abbcss@g" the error is gone and as you can see the email is still not valid. for better understanding i put a fiddle here.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#email').keyup(function(){
   $('#checkform').validate();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<form id="checkform">
<input id="email" type="email" name="email">
</form>
<hr>
<p>Try to put first "abcc" and click outside field </p>
<p>then try to put "abcc@gmail" and click outside field </p>
<p>it will consider it a valid email but actually it is not.</p>
```

any help regarding this issue will be appriciate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can validate email by using jquery validation plugin [add method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validate_email", function(value, element) {

    if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, "Please enter a valid Email.");

$('#checkform').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            validate_email: true
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Except for testing if there is a value present prior to validating, this is the exact same code posted in the two other answers.  In my case, I have an ***optional*** email field that I want to validate, but only if an email address is entered.

```
$.validator.addMethod("OptionalButValidEmail", function (value, element) {
    // only test for email address validity if something is entered
    if (value.length > 1) {
        if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "Please enter a valid Email.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  'validateEmail',
  function(value, element) {
    return (
      this.optional(element) ||
      /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(
        value
      )
    );
  },
  'Please enter a valid email address.'
);

$('#form').validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      validateEmail: true,
    },
});
```

Comment: This answer isn't really any different from the one posted above and you posted it about 2 years after. Not sure why you posted it...